# Confusion with collections of nested generics

Tags: java, generics, collections, covariance, contravariance

Please help me understand why `add1()` and `add4()` report errors and why `add2()` and `add3()` don't.  Specifically, please show examples of undesired consequences if the compiler allowed each of these to compile.

```
class InnerTypeConfusion {
   interface Animal {}
   class Dog implements Animal {}
   class Room<T> {
      void add(T t) {}
   }

   void add1(Room<? extends Animal> room) {
      // Error: The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Animal) in the type 
      // Room<capture#1-of ? extends Animal> is not applicable for the 
      // arguments (Dog)
      room.add(new Dog());
   }

   void add2(Room<Animal> room) {
      room.add(new Dog());
   }

   class Cage<T> {}

   void add3(Room<Cage<? extends Animal>> room) {
      room.add(new Cage<Dog>());
   }

   void add4(Room<Cage<Animal>> room) {
      // The method add(Cage<Animal>) in the type Room<Cage<Animal>> is not 
      // applicable for the arguments (Cage<Dog>)
      room.add(new Cage<Dog>());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the method `void add1(Room<? extends Animal> room)`, you define that the method accepts a `Room` that holds an `Animal`.   For example, it can be `Room<Cat>`, or `Room<Dog>`--even `Room<Animal>` for holding all types of animals.  However, keep in mind that the room has been created outside this method call and you can't make any assumptions about the room type other than that it holds either a specific animal.

```
add1(new Room<Dog>()); // give the method a room for dogs
add1(new Room<Cat>()); // give the method a room for cats
add1(new Room<Animal>()); // give the method a room for any animal
```

But once you're inside the method, you can't know specifically which type of room had been passed.

It would be valid to call the method with a room for only birds `add1(new Room<Bird>())`, as `Bird` does indeed extend `Animal`. However in the method body, you are adding a `Dog` into it. That's why it's invalid, we can't put `Dog` objects into `Room<Bird>`. It is a `Room` of **some** kind of animals and not a `Room` of **any** kind of animals.

If you wanted to write a method that added a dog to a room appropriate for adding dogs (but not limited to just dog-only rooms), you'd write it with signature `addDogToRoom(Room<? super Dog> room)` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929382/403455).  This method could accept `Room<Animal>` as well as `Room<Dog>` and still within the method add new dogs to the room.

As about `add4`, it's the same but the opposite. With `Room<Cage<Animal>>` you specify that the method requires a specific room type--a room that allows only cages that hold **any** kind of `Animal`. But then you are trying to put a `Cage<Dog>` into it, a cage that allows **only** dogs. Therefore, it's invalid again.

**Addition regarding comment:**

Let's say there are cages designed for containing cats `Cage<Cat>` and cages designed for containing dogs `Cage<Dog>`. There are also universal cages, which can contain any kind of animal `Cage<Animal>`. Those are three different kinds of cages, they can't be substituted for one another, as they have totally different architecture and design.

- `void method(Cage<Dog>)` means that the method needs one dog cage.
- `void method(Cage<Animal>)` means that the method needs one universal cage.
- `void method(Cage<? extends Animal>)` means that the method needs any kind of animal cage. Either dog cage, cat cage or universal cage.

Rooms are another level of abstraction--visualize them as a rooms with cages inside. There can be a room for storing cat cages `Room<Cage<Cat>>`, a room for storing dog cages `Room<Cage<Dog>>`, a room for storing universal cages `Room<Cage<Animal>>` and a room for storing **multiple kinds of** animal cages `Room<Cage<? extends Animal>>`. Therefore, the same rules apply:

- `void method(Room<Cage<Dog>>)` - room of dog cages
- `void method(Room<Cage<Cat>>)` - room of cat cages
- `void method(Room<Cage<Animal>>)` - room of animal cages
- `void method(Room<Cage<? extends Animal>>)` - room that can contain **multiple kinds of** animal cages.  E.g., the room could simultaneously contain a `Cage<Dog>`, and a `Cage<Animal>`.

Now, in `add3(Room<Cage<? extends Animal>> room)`, you request a last kind of room, the one that can contain "all kinds of animal cages". Therefore the room passed to the method can contain or add new dog cages `room.add(new Cage<Dog>())` or any other type of cage.

However, to call that method, you would need to first create a new "universal" room (which supports all cages):

```
Room<Cage<? extends Animal>> room = new Room<Cage<? extends Animal>>();
add3(room);
```

Giving it a room of dog cages will not work:

```
// Here we create a room that can contain only dog cages
Room<Cage<Dog>> room = new Room<Cage<Dog>>(); 

// But the method needs a "any kind of animal cage" room
// Therefore we get error during compilation
add3(room);
```

If you wanted to write a more flexible method that accepts rooms capable at minimum of holding dog cages, it could look like this:

```
void add(Room<Cage<? super Dog>> room) {
   room.add(new Cage<Dog>());
   room.add(new Cage<Animal>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so now I clearly understand why `add1()` shouldn't compile, but now I don't understand why `add3()` compiles correctly.

Comment: @glenviewjeff It was wrong, so I removed it to rewrite it using different wording.

Comment: @glenviewjeff Ok, wrote detailed explanation on the subject. Hope that helps.

Comment: Max I hope you don't mind that I heavily edited your answer rather than adding my own answer.  Thanks very much--I learned a lot as a result of this question!

Comment: @glenviewjeff No problem and thanks for additions, maybe someone will also find it useful as you did :)

Answer (score 1):

For `add1`:

```
// We don't want to add a Dog to a room of cats...
Room<Cat> cats = new Room<Cat>();
add1(cats);
Cat cat = cats.get(0);
```

For `add4`, we don't want to add a `Cage<Dog>` to a `Room` of `Cage<Animal>`... A `Cage<Dog>` *isn't* a `Cage<Animal>`, although it *is* a `Cage<? extends Animal>`. It's similar to the first cast, just with one more level of nesting...

Comment: Thanks, so now I clearly understand why `add1()` shouldn't compile, but now I don't understand why `add3()` compiles correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a list of unknown type, marked with `?`, the list is pretty much read only. You can insert only `null` into it. You cannot consume the items in the list. Here you deal with an unknown subclass of `Animal`

```
void add1(List<? extends Animal> list) {
   list.add(new Dog());
}
```

Even though `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`, a `List` of `Dog` is not a subclass of a `List` of `Animal`. Java doesn't know this automatically so you have to specify it by hand, like you did in `add3(..)`

```
void add4(List<Cage<Animal>> list) {
   list.add(new Cage<Dog>());
}
```

Comment: Adrian, I'm not sure what you were trying to show with the added cast to `Animal` in your version of `add1`.  Were you just showing the implicit cast?  You know this version of `add1()` also won't compile, right?

Comment: @glenviewjeff What he says is that if your method argument is defined as `Cage<? extends Animal>` (cage for some type of animal), you can not be sure which kind of cage you received. Therefore, you can't be sure which kind of animal you can put inside. Therefore, Java will not allow you to put anything inside, unless you cast it to some kind of _specific_ cage. For example: `((Cage<Dog>)receivedCage).put(new Dog())`.

Comment: I like that you explained the read-only dimension of `add1`.  It's read-only because there's no way to determine what the actual type is of the list.  However, I don't understand what you're getting at in pasting `add4` unmodified.  Did you mean to change something to cause it to compile?

Comment: @glenviewjeff no I meant to reply to the code he posted so I included the code. I was hoping it would make my reply more clear because you see to what part of the code I'm referring to.