# Is it possible to write a single method that accepts a generic parameter of varying abstraction?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, pecs

As a [followup to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9890866/403455), is it possible to write a single method that adds a `Dog` to a suitable room?  (In this example, it would accept either an `Animal` room or a `Dog` room.)  Or am I forced to write two distinct methods as below?  (I can't even rely on overloading because of type erasure).

```
public class Rooms {
   interface Animal {}
   class Dog implements Animal {}
   class Room<T> {
      void add(T t) {}
   }

   void addDogToAnimalRoom(Room<Animal> room) {
      room.add(new Dog());
   }

   void addDogToDogRoom(Room<Dog> room) {
      room.add(new Dog());
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `Room` as a consumer, since it's accepting the new `Dog`, so Josh Bloch's famous [PECS acronym](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA136&ots=yYFiIhv0T2&dq=PECS%20stands%20for%20producer-extends,%20consumer-super&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q=PECS%20stands%20for%20producer-extends,%20consumer-super&f=false) applies.

```
void addDogToDogRoom(Room<? super Dog> room) {
  room.add(new Dog());
}
```

Comment: Oh *that's* what super is for :)

Comment: Yep!  You're using `List` as a consumer, since it's accepting the new Dog, so Josh Bloch's famous PECS acronym applies.

Comment: This is the danger of learn-as-you-go programming.  I "read" his book, but only the parts that were relevant at the time.  I think understanding this could have saved me much unnecessary refactoring.  Please feel free to suggest (or just edit) a better question title.